# Using case with an aggregate function

Tags: sql

I'm trying to count the number of customers that bought more than 10 items from a store a specific month that bought less than 10 items from the previous month (only has 2 months, 01 and 02)

For example,

```
id        items_bought        month
0001        11                  02
0001         9                  01
0003         8                  02
0003         8                  01
0005         13                 02
0006         16                 02
0006         17                 01
```

this would return a count of 1.

My idea was to do a case statement like

```
   case 
     when (month = '02' and items_bought > 10) and (month = '01' and items_bought < 10) then 1
   else 0
end as c
```

and then kind of do a select c, count(c) where c = 1
but then I realized this wouldn't help since I would need to group by ids' and I'm kind of stuck where to continue.

Answer (score 0):

You use `Sum` over `Case` like this:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id
HAVING  SUM(   CASE
                  WHEN (
                           month = '02'
                           AND items_bought > 10
                       )
                       AND
                       (
                           month = '01'
                           AND items_bought < 10
                       ) THEN
                      1
                  ELSE
                      0
              END
          )=1
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example you could use `count` with a correlated `exists`

```
select Count(Id)
from t 
where t.items_bought > 10 and t.month = 2
and exists (
  select * from t t2 
  where t2.id = t.id and t2.items_bought < 10 and t2.month = t.2month - 1
);
```

Comment: what about the month?

Comment: @hjun ah my bad copy & paste fail, should have also included the month in the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Use lag to get the previous month data and then you have in each row all the information you need in order to filter.

```
select count(*) as cnt

from  (select id 
             ,items_bought
             ,month
             ,lag(items_bought, 1) over (partition by id order by month) as items_bought_LM
       
       from   t
       ) t

where  items_bought > 10 and items_bought_LM < 10
```

| cnt |
| --- |
| 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9e346f1db8f8144ac3d82ae78c48c79d)